# Create overaly textfields in ITextFields in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

My project has a requirement of drawing 4 editable textFields (signatures) overlapping each other in PDF such that client can enter text in either of the textFields and that text should be visible on the form.

The issue here is the textFields are opaque and a textField on top is hiding the text of all the textFields that are drawn before them.

Any solution or workaround will be very helpful.

*Below mentioned is the code*:

```
    private void AddTextFieldsToPDF()
    {
        {
            // The yOffset will move the text boxes above the signature line instead of somewhat on it.
    //OwnerSignYPosition : Float containing y-axis position of textField
    //Stacking one text field over other
            AddTextField(_reportDocument.DocWriter, "Field1", "field1", true, 40, OwnerSignYPos, 380, 18);
            AddTextField(_reportDocument.DocWriter, "Field2", "field2", true, 40, OwnerSignYPos, 380, 18);
            AddTextField(_reportDocument.DocWriter, "Field3", "field3", true, 40, OwnerSignYPos, 380, 18);
            AddTextField(_reportDocument.DocWriter, "Field4", "field4", true, 40, OwnerSignYPos, 380, 18);
        }
    }

protected void AddTextField(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, String fieldId, String fieldText, Boolean isSignature, float xPosition, float yPosition, float width, float height)
    {
        Rectangle position = new Rectangle(xPosition, yPosition, xPosition + width, Math.Max(yPosition - height, 0));
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField field = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(writer, position, text);

        field.Text = fieldText;

        field.Box.BackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
        field.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Narrow").BaseFont;
        field.TextColor = Color.WHITE; //new Color(0, 0, 255); // White
        field.FontSize = 9;
        writer.AddAnnotation(field.GetTextField());
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code as well.

Comment: And by *signatures* you don't mean digital signatures, do you?

Comment: Those fields not merely overlap, they coincide. How do you expect the user to select a special field?

Comment: Solved: I just kept textfield background color unassigned and text in the fields is showing up with some opacity; quite visible.

Comment: Later, I used Javascript to hide blank textFields. This made my text appear better.
I will definitely share my workaround when I get some time after finishing my project.

Thanks for the help :)